# Test Suite doesn't end if one of the test fails

Tags: testng

I have a test suite in TestNG that looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="CBT test">
<test name="util-test" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
    <classes>
        <class name="Class2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="integration-test">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="CBTTest_1"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="Class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="basic_test">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="CBTTest_2"/>
            <include name="basic"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="Class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

The issue is: if say one of the test method in "Integrations test" fails then rest of the tests are ignored, but, the test suite keeps on running even after rest of the test cases in "basic_test" is executed/ignored (incase of failure in "basic_test". I need to find a way to make sure that the test suite ends execution once the test cases are either successful or failed or ignored.

Comment: what test it is. which tool / framework you are using. try to give very specific example. Then probably somebody will answer you.

Comment: Oh I missed it. I am using TestNG for testing.

Comment: Probably somebody having fair knowledge on TestNG may reply you. I have not used it anytime. Sorry.